# Output one value in foreach loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am looping through a folder with files,  to select some of them accordingly if they match the day that we are currently.
I want to output a message if it doesn't file any file that matches the day, but I only what one message to be outputted instead of a message for each file.

Any clues on how to make that happen in my code below:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $directory) {
        
        if ($file.LastWriteTime.Date -eq [datetime]::Today) {
            Write-Output "File from today"

        } else {
            Write-Output "File is not from today"
        } 
   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store if you found a a search result in a boolean variable.

```
$hasFile = $false 
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $directory) 
    if ($file.LastWriteTime.Date -eq [datetime]::Today) {
            Write-Output "File from today"
            $hasFile = $true
     }
}

if ($hasFile -eq $false) {
   Write-Output "No file found"
}
```

Comment: Imagine i have 3 files from today and I want to output a message with the respective filename, only one per file. How would I do that.

Comment: I have done like you suggested it works for the files than don't match today's date. But for files that match, instead of 3 messages it displays 9messages, 3 for each.

Comment: please post a new question

Answer (score 2):

I think you could approach it this way, first try to find any files from today and, if there are none, then display the message.

**Note:** I have added the `-File` switch to find only files, else we would be also looking at folders which would be not intended.

```
$todayFiles = Get-ChildItem . -File | Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq [datetime]::Today
}

if ($todayFiles) {
    $todayFiles | ForEach-Object { "File from Today => {0}" -f $_.FullName }
} else {
    "File is not from today"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Santiago I used the answer from vinzBad, but your suggestion is also valid. I will up vote your answer!